# Response.Write print text from database as HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm storing text from a textarea to my database. This text can contain new lines, special characters etc. However I want to make sure that when I show it using response.write, it comes out exactly as if it was to show in the textarea control. The reason why I want to do this is because I want to give the user a print view form. The solution below does not work. Using ASP.NET/C#

e.g

```
foreach (DataRow row in dview.Table.Rows)
{
Response.Write("<tr>");
                    Response.Write(String.Format("<td>{0}<br/><br/></td>",   row[1].ToString().Replace("\n", "<br/>")));
                    Response.Write("</tr>");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Never use "`\n`" always use `Environment.NewLine`, instead:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dview.Table.Rows)
{
    Response.Write("<tr>"); 
    Response.Write(String.Format("<td>{0}<br/><br/></td>", row[1].ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>")));
    Response.Write("</tr>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it that way, you'll run into problems, especially when quotes and symbols are involved.

Store the data like this :

```
 HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>"); //your HTML to encode goes here
```

And retrieve it like this:

```
myPlaceHolder.Text = HttpUtility.HTMLDecode(myData);
```

Here's a little more information on [HTMLEncode/Decode](http://bdwebster.com/2008/03/05/htmlencode-in-aspnet/)

Comment: Sometimes the data entered does not contain HTML and you want to translate it to work as the user entered it in HTML. What do you suggest then? Fudging data input which goes against data entry concepts?

Comment: I don't understand.
`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode( HttpUtility.HtmlEncode( myString ) ) = myString`
Always. So even if they did not enter HTML, the data will come back the same as they entered it.

Comment: The user enters plain text. Not through a WYSIWYG editor. They enter "Hello<enter>world". You want to display it back to them as "Hello<new line>world". Your method is fine for when the output matches the input, but when the output format does not match the input, you would have to fudge the data to make it work. The poster is requesting how to change the format on output, not input.

Comment: Also: Fudging data is any type of data alteration of user input before storing it. Altering the form of the data is not fudging (encryption). However encoding and decoding, is. I am also in disagreement that all data should be encoded before storing. I believe all output should be encoded unless HTML is allowed. Malicious data should be prevented by the UI.

Comment: The client/UI is not the only place for validation. Validation should take place client-side and server-side. Server-side validation is an additional and critical piece to making sure bad data is not entered in the case client-side validation is circumvented.

Comment: UI does not refer to client side. UI refers to the UI layer which includes server side code FOR the client UI. Just fyi.

Answer (score 1):

You could display the output inside a `<pre></pre>` block which will preserve all whitespace, including multiple spaces, newlines, etc.

HTML encoding is recommended so any angle brackets in the data don't break the output HTML.